# How do I export one letter of a cell to a CSV-File?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

So here is my problem or my lack of knowledge...I'm exporting a few columns of a worksheet into a csv-file. 
The columns will be written in one cell in one line like that ->

Bauer M,"90","colleagues","active"

So in my Excel it looks like this ->

Bauer Martin 90 (and each word in one cell)

So my question is...how do I get only the first later of the name Martin in my CSV-file...my code is down below...I just started coding like 3 days ago so I'm sorry if it's not perfect...

```
Private Sub btn_erstellen_Click()
Dim My_filenumber As Integer
Dim logSTR As String
Dim i, j As Integer
i = tb_dw1.Value
j = tb_dw2.Value


My_filenumber = FreeFile
Open "C:\test\Sample.csv" For Append As #My_filenumber

Do While Not Cells(i, "B").Value = ""
If i = j + 1 Then
    Exit Do
Else
    If Cells(i, "F").Text = "inaktiv" Or Cells(i, "A").Text = "INTERNER" Then
        i = i + 1
    Else
        If Cells(i, "A").Value = "-" Then
        logSTR = Cells(i, "B").Value & ","
        Else
        logSTR = Cells(i, "A").Value & " "
        logSTR = logSTR & Cells(i, "B").Value & ","
        End If
        logSTR = logSTR & """"
        logSTR = logSTR & Cells(i, "C").Value
        logSTR = logSTR & """" & "," & """" & "colleagues" & """" & "," & """" & "active" & """"
        i = i + 1
        Print #My_filenumber, logSTR
    End If
End If
Loop

Close #My_filenumber
End Sub
```

Comment: Not clear enough for me. Do you mean that one cell has the value `Bauer Martin 90 colleagues active` and you want to convert it to `Bauer M,"90","colleagues","active"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

`Cells(i, "B").Value & ","`

with

`Mid(Cells(i, "B").Value,1,1) & ","`

The first part refers to a value on a certain cell. By using `Mid` it will allow you to extract part of the contents of it.

Its usage is `Mid(STRING,WHERE_IT_STARTS,HOW_MANY_CHARACTERS)`. In this case, it will get the value from `Cells(i, "B").Value`, and from the first digit, it will extract one digit (The `1,1` on the code I suggested)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Is this better?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Left(string, Length) function.  This would look something like `left(Range("A1").value, 1)` for your case.